# How to register program options so that they can be auto completed with tab?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

This was the best way how I thought to pose this question.

So, let's say I have a cpp program named `foo` and, when called from command line, it can use a flag `--config` (e.g.`$ ./foo --config path/to/config_file`)

How can I make it possible to auto finish `--config` using tab key after typing `./foo --c`?

So
`$./foo --c` -> *press Tab* -> `$./foo --config`

Comment: This is configured in your shell with bash programmable completion. If you're seeing this behavior for other commands, you probably have the popular third party package `bash-completion` installed. You can look up how to write completion scripts for it

Comment: @thatotherguy It depends on the shell. zsh is the default shell in MacOS and Arch Linux and it's becoming more common and popular.

Comment: @pGos : According to the tags of your question, you ask about Posix Shell, but AFIK this shell does not have completion.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu terminal.
@thatotherguy, that was exactly what I've been looking for. So now I know it is called bash-completion. Thank you! I also found a nice tutorial about it, now that I knew what to look for :) https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/add-bash-auto-completion-in-ubuntu-linux/